# Java Regex to get a word from a String

Tags: java, regex

How can I use a regex in java for the following?

```
String code = "import java.io.*;"  +
              "import java.util.*;"  +
              "public class Test1 extends Exam{" +
                  " // my code " +
              "}";
```

from the String above how can I get the class name **Test1** exactly.

Comment: will there always be `extends`?

Comment: You can use a captured group: `/.*class (\S+) .*/`

Comment: yes may be extends or implements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
String className = code.replaceAll("(?s)^.*?(?:public|protected|private)?\\s*(?:\\s+static\\s+)?class\\s+(\\S+).*$", "$1");
//=> Test1
```

Comment: `(?:public|protected|private)?(?:\s+static)?\s+class`

Comment: @anubhava your previous one is work. this updated one is not work.

Comment: Yes previous one was also working with your example and I had tested it.

Comment: perfect experts... thanks a lot @anubhava ..  can you please explain shortly how it is work..

Comment: `(?s)` is for making dot match new lines. Then it matches any one of `public|protected|private` keywords followed by optional `static` and then followed by `class`. After that it captures `\\s+` (i.e. non-space characters) and in the replacement part it replaces whole string with this `captured group #1`.

Comment: where can i learn it, any tutorial? i am try in google, but no one give clear explain.

Comment: @subash You could also have a look at [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/), which generates a diagram on the fly given a regexp. Quite a great tool ;)